# Removing light fixture causes circuit breaker to trip

Tags: electrical, lighting, electrical-panel, light-fixture

I was replacing a ceiling light fixture with a lower one. I had turned off the circuit breaker to remove the lamp and disconnect the 3 wires - black, white, and bronze. Then, I tried to turn the circuit breaker on again ( *after ensuring the wires are not touching one another* ).

However, I am unable to turn on the circuit breaker switch as the tripped light turns on and doesn't even click when i turn the switch all the way on.

I have tried putting a new light in and then turning the switch on to see if that works, but that doesn't either.
I am not sure why this is happening.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: "*with a lower one*"  What is a lower one ? "*However, I am unable to turn on the circuit breaker switch as the tripped light turns on and doesn't even click when i turn the switch all the way on.*" Can  you provide a more clear description of what this means. Please

Comment: Light? On a breaker? ? Does this breaker have a TEST  button?

Comment: @AlaskaMan it is a hanging light, which many taller members of my family keep bumping their head against. I am replacing it with another light that does not hang as low in the air, but is shorter.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica, yes this breaker does have a test button. I believe this is an arc fault breaker. It also has a red button with the word "TRIP" next to it. It is this red light that is now on for the one breaker while all the other breakers still have this red light off.

Comment: What make and model of breaker panel do you have?